# how to get values of particular xml node in c# loop and replace it with other value

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xml

I have response xml in a string named getval.
   I want to select all "fromsector" node value and replace that value with corresponding value from database.Say for example:`Ban` should be replaced with `bangalore`..

I tried XmlNodeList and XmlNode.But none of them worked..
   Any help please.

**c#**

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml"));
                    XmlNodeList fromselectors;
                    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
                    fromselectors = root.SelectNodes("SearchResults/FlightSegments/Flights/LegDetails/Leg/FromSector");
                    foreach (XmlNode n in fromselectors)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        string xmls = n.InnerXml;
                        cmd.CommandText = "select City from CCode where Code='" + xmls + "'";
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml"));
```

Comment: If your problem is finding "FromSector" elements no matter where they are in the xml, then the answer is XPATH. try XmlDocument.Select("//FromSector") and this will give you a collection of all nodes. you can then replace the values of each by a simple string.Replace()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XPath to get the required nodes from the xml and update the values

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/temp.xml"));

        //Selecting node with number='3'
        XmlNodeList fromselectors;
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        fromselectors = root.SelectNodes("SearchResults/FlightSegments/Flights/LegDetails/Leg/FromSector");

        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        foreach (XmlNode n in fromselectors)
        {                                   
           string xmls = n.InnerXml;
           cmd.CommandText = "select City from CCode where Code='" + xmls + "'";
           string city = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
           n.InnerText = city;
        }
        con.Close();
        doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/temp.xml"));
```

Comment: will it find all Fromsector nodes

Comment: yes.. it will select all "FromSecotr" nodes throughout the xml

Comment: patel i used ur code, but i have some problem..sql is not being executed.I updated my code above..can u please have a look..

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ??? use ExecuteScalar() for getting single value. Also you are not updating value of your node in the for loop. And you should not execute sql query for each node if the loop is going to be big.

Comment: hmmm.. i have changed my reply. please see it. You should open connection before loop and close it after loop. Also Scalar is faster than reader